# Where to safely store SSH/AWS/etc. keys for infrastructure provisioning from Jenkins?

Tags: security, jenkins

I have already moved out all passwords and aws_access/secret_keys, out of the Git repositories.

Some access_keys/secret_keys have now been made available as environment variables so that the pipelines still work.

I'm looking for a simple, easy, not too complex-solution that will give us a basic security for storing secrets that's more secure than saving passwords as environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a [built-in credentials store](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) that's made for exactly this purpose.  Out of the box, it supports SSH keypairs, username/password credentials, and a couple other types.  I've used these in both old-style Freestyle jobs and new-style Pipeline jobs with great success.